# How to add search parameters to GET request in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

After having read through and completed the [Django REST Framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization), it is not completely obvious how one would implement a filter on a GET request. For example, [ListAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#listapiview) is great for viewing all the instances of a Model in your database. However, if I wanted to limit the results (e.g. for a `Book` model, I might want to limit the results by publication date or author, etc.). It seems the best way to do this would be to create a custom Serializer, View, etc. and basically write everything by hand.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search parameters are called filter parameters in terms of django-rest-framework. There are many ways to apply the filtering, check the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering).

In most cases, you need to override just view, not serializer or any other module.

One obvious approach to do it, is to override view's queryset. Example:

```
# access to /api/foo/?category=animal

class FooListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Foo
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(FooListView, self).get_queryset()
        category = self.request.query_params.get("category", None)
        if category:
            qs = qs.filter(category=category)
        return qs
```

But, django-rest-framework allows to do such things automatically, using [django-filter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#api-guide).

Install it first:

```
pip install django-filter
```

Then specify in your view, by what fields you want to filter:

```
class FooListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Foo
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    filter_fields = ('category', )
```

This will do the same, as in previous example, but less code used.

There are many ways to customize this filtering, look [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#specifying-a-filterset) and [here](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) for details.

There is also a way to apply [filtering globally](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#generic-filtering):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```