# DRF: Route with and without arguments

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a pretty simple urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products', views.ProductViewSet, basename = "product")

urlpatterns = [
    url('^api/', include(router.urls)), ...]
```

where `Product` looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="User", blank = True)
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=120)
```

What I want is a view that returns products from a user, if a user is handed to it, and returns all products when no user is submitted. I read multiple posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324756/where-can-i-access-request-parameters-in-django-rest-framework), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924968/how-to-add-search-parameters-to-get-request-in-django-rest-framework?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207014/how-to-access-get-request-data-in-django-rest-framework) but I could not solve it. Getting all products works:

```
class ProductViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, viewsets.ViewSet):
    login_url = "/login/"

    def list(self, request):
        data = [{"products": Product.objects.all(),}]
        results = ProductSerializer(data, many = True).data
        return Response(results)
```

Serializer.py:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    products = serializers.CharField(max_length = 120)
```

Can I add another method to my `ProductViewSet`, and how do I have to alter the urls.py so that I can call (for `User` with `id=1`):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8002/api/products/1
```

Edit: For example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63007742/4225972) suggest handling data in the request with request.query_params.get('username') but appending data to my url leads to 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering a query through a REST API the convention is to use query params. ie.
`/products?user=1` instead of `/product/user/1` or `/product/1`.

To acheive this you could do something like this, where you would use the url /products?user=1

```
class ProductViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, viewsets.ViewSet):
    login_url = "/login/"

    def list(self, request):
        user_id = request.GET.get('user') #get id from query params, None if not provided
        query = Product.objects.all()
        if user_id:
            query = query.filter(user=user_id)
        data = [{"products": query,}]
        results = ProductSerializer(data, many = True).data
        return Response(results)
```

**OR**

Even easier, use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)